# Плиточный дизайн и горизонтальный скролл

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте, хочу создать такой дизайн [image: Плиточный дизайн]

Задать фиксированную высоту контейнера, горизонтальный скролл и функцию вставки картинки, но из-за горизонтального скрола все картинки идут в одну линию, а не друг под другом, а я хочу чтобы сначала шла колонка в три картинки (сверху вниз), а потом новая колонка с тремя картинками сверху вниз (пускай все картинки будут одинаковой ширины и высоты).

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #edf0f4;
  height: 760px
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.test {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
}

.gallery::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #d1dae3;
}

.gallery::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.gallery::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #21b8c6;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="test"></div>
      <div class="test"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Получается такая ерунда [image: Неудачный плиточный дизайн]

Как разместить элементы в несколько линий при горизонтальном скролле? Можно ли использовать только HTML и СSS или придется добавить javascript? Может есть какой-то плагин для этих целей?

Comment: `display:flex`, `flex-direction:column` - как вариант

Comment: Пробовал, тогда все элементы идут в одну колонку

Comment: надо добавить еще `flex-wrap:wrap`

Comment: Точно, теперь все заработало, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если ширина одинаковая то нужно поправить .gallery и декоративно .test

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #edf0f4;
  height: 760px
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
/*  white-space: nowrap;*/
/*  display: inline-block;*/
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 5px;
}

.test {
  display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: red;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.gallery::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #d1dae3;
}

.gallery::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.gallery::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #21b8c6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="test">1</div>
        <div class="test">2</div>
        <div class="test">3</div>
        <div class="test">4</div>
        <div class="test">5</div>
        <div class="test">6</div>
        <div class="test">7</div>
        <div class="test">8</div>
        <div class="test">9</div>
        <div class="test">10</div>
        <div class="test">11</div>
        <div class="test">12</div>
        <div class="test">13</div>
        <div class="test">14</div>
        <div class="test">15</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #edf0f4;
  height: 400px
}

.gallery {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 920px;
  height: 100%;
}

.test {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.gallery::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #d1dae3;
}

.gallery::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.gallery::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  background-color: #21b8c6;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
        <div class="test"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```